# On page load, div visible for a moment

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When my page refreshes, I can see this div for few seconds and then it goes away. How can I control this behaviour?

```
<div ng-cloak="true" ng-show="userFromGuardian">

    <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/orangeIcon_normal.gif" style="vertical-align: top"/>
        <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: -2%"><span style="font-family:Century Gothic;font-size:48px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;color: #FF6600;">Online Quotation Tool</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="headerGuardian">
        <span style="text-align: left;margin-left: 1%;font-weight: normal;">Welcome</span>
        <span style="text-align: left"> {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</span>
        <a style="margin-right: 1%;float: right"  ng-click="logOut()">logout</a>
    </div>

</div>

       //checking Guardian user
        $rootScope.userFromGuardian =false;
        UserFromGuardian.get(function(data){
            $rootScope.userFromGuardian = data.userFromGuardianFlag;});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you use `ng-show="userFromGuardian"`to the div.
If you remove `ng-show="userFromGuardian"` then div will show.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `style="display:none;"`

```
<div ng-cloak="true" ng-show="userFromGuardian" style="display:none;">
```

Javascript and CSS can't be relied upon to hide your div immediately.